# Two different definitions of Derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Here are two definition of derivations

> > **Definition 1** Let $A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of commutative algebras, and $M$ a
> >     $B$-module. We define the derivations
> >                     $Der_A (B, M ) = \{D : D : B → M $satisfying (1) and (2)$\}$
> >
> > (1) $D(b_1 b_2 ) = b_1 D(b_2 ) + b_2 D(b_1 )$
> >
> > (2) $D(a) = 0  \forall a \in A$

Here is the second definition

> > If $S$ is a ring and $M$ is an $S$ module, then a map $d:S \leftarrow M$ is a derivation if satisfies
> >
> > $$ d(fg)=fdg  +gdf$$
> >
> > If $S$ is an $R$-algebra, then we say that $d$ is $R$-linear if it is a map of $R$-modules

Can someone explain me how these two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: DOes the second of these definitions really have the arrow pointing backwards? What does that notation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Definition 1, observe that (2) is equivalent to the $A$-linearity of $D$. Namely, (1) implies $D(1)=D(1 \cdot 1)=D(1)+D(1)$, hence $D(1)=0$. If $D$ is $A$-linear, it follows $D|_A = 0$. If conversely $D|_A = 0$, then (1) easily implies that $D$ is $A$-linear.

From this it immediatey follows that Definitions 1 and 2 are equivalent (with $S=B, R = A, d = D$).